# How to build an http request filter using nginx and/or python?

Tags: python, http, nginx, webserver, mysql-connector

I am new to web programming and I want to ask for some guide or directions. I have searched quite a bit but none of the tech articles are addressing my specific needs:

I'm building an app where users can send pictures and make some fun tweeks on the picture. 
currently I have two virtual machines in the cloud:

user ------> Router_Server --------> Application_Server

All http requests will go through the Router server first for some identity check and authentication. An nginx service is running on the Router server.

The Application server is where the pictures are saved and where the algorithm for tweaking the pictures takes place.

Currently there is no multi-tenant mechanism implemented. if User A is authenticated to visit the application server, then he can view user B's photos if he has the correct url, which is easy to guess.

I want to build a MySQL table in the Router, listing the user id and the photo id that he/she owns. If user A tries to send an http request to view a photo that doesn't belong to him, or  visit the URL containing the photo id of other people, nginx should simply return 403 to him.

The direction I'm going is to write a python script that:

1. When a user sends a photo, we fetch user id and photo id from the http request and update the MySQL table with the user_id and photo_id info.
2. When a user requests to view a photo, we check the table to see if the photo id in the http request belongs to the user. If yes, we pass the http request to application server; if not, we return 403 to the user.

I'm new to nginx. Is it possible to integrate such a python/mysql module into the nginx config? 
Or am I going in the wrong direction to approach this problem?

Comment: If you want to do more of this in Nginx, consider [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/en/) which supports Lua scripting.

Comment: Nginx can run python web apps as wsgi modules.